# Is it okay if I don't replace my laptop battery as long as it works by plugging it in?

Tags: laptop, battery

I got a laptop and the battery is defective. It does not increase the charging percentage, it always stays at 3-8%. If I remove the charger manually, it will turn off. Is it okay if I don't replace the battery as long as I can use it by always plugging it in? When I am working with my laptop sometimes it shuts down immediately even if is plugged in. Is that okay?

Comment: It's not OK, but then it's not not-OK either. The battery on a laptop serves two purposes: 1) Power the laptop when you can't or won't plug the power cord in; and 2) Act as a buffer between the main power source (the wall socket, then the charger) and the motherboard, to deliver a steady power in terms of both voltage and intensity, so that the electronic components in your PC won't "fry".You can leave the battery inside, or plain remove it (if it's removable) if you prefer. You just need a power source, after all. Your CPU *could* be underclocked in the absence of a battery, though.

Comment: what if my laptop has a non removable battery or a built in battery? What should I do about this? Can I leave this as is? Since im not planning to repair or upgrade this and i am switching to pc soon. @Didier

Comment: Yes, it's OK, but apparently, you're not on Windows, and each OS (Windows, macOS, Linux, what have you) has its own way to deal with a damaged or absent battery. What OS are you running on this laptop?

Comment: I am running windows 10, 64bit. This laptop was pretty old. It was about 5 years from me since i am on college

Comment: Then you should be fine leaving the battery inside, and using it with the power cord attached. If you notice a swelling under the keyboard or the underside of the laptop, though, disconnect it from the power source immediately and turn it off. It'll mean your battery is swollen, due to a corruption of the electrolyte inside, and it could be dangerous. The best thing to do would really be to have that battery replaced, as soon as you possibly can.

Comment: I have been using a laptop whose battery is dead since last 10 months. I mean dead... completely dead. I have faced no issues till date, just the charging indicator blinks on and off all the time and I have to keep it plugged, always. That's it.